# TensorFlow Cifar10 cost finding error of logits and labels (logits and labels must be same size)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Hello there I hope you guys are in good health. I am working on tensorflow and traning my neural network on cifar 10 dataset I am working on kaggle. I am new to this field and have many complicated problems. seeking for your help thank you.

**Here is my code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
import os
import platform
from subprocess import check_output
classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')
x=tf.placeholder('float',[None,3072])
y=tf.placeholder('float')
%matplotlib inline

def load_pickle(f):
    version = platform.python_version_tuple()
    if version[0] == '2':
        return  pickle.load(f)
    elif version[0] == '3':
        return  pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
    raise ValueError("invalid python version: {}".format(version))

def load_CIFAR_batch(filename):
    """ load single batch of cifar """
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        datadict = load_pickle(f)
        X = datadict['data']
        Y = datadict['labels']
        X = X.reshape(10000,3072)
        Y = np.array(Y)
        return X, Y

def load_CIFAR10(ROOT):
    """ load all of cifar """
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for b in range(1,6):
        f = os.path.join(ROOT, 'data_batch_%d' % (b, ))
        X, Y = load_CIFAR_batch(f)
        xs.append(X)
        ys.append(Y)
    Xtr = np.concatenate(xs)
    Ytr = np.concatenate(ys)
    del X, Y
    Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR_batch(os.path.join(ROOT, 'test_batch'))
    return Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte
def get_CIFAR10_data(num_training=49000, num_validation=1000, num_test=10000):
    # Load the raw CIFAR-10 data
    cifar10_dir = '../input/cifar-10-batches-py/'
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_CIFAR10(cifar10_dir)

    # Subsample the data
    mask = range(num_training, num_training + num_validation)
    X_val = X_train[mask]
    y_val = y_train[mask]
    mask = range(num_training)
    X_train = X_train[mask]
    y_train = y_train[mask]
    mask = range(num_test)
    X_test = X_test[mask]
    y_test = y_test[mask]

    # Normalize the data: subtract the mean image


    return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test


# Invoke the above function to get our data.
x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, x_test, y_test = get_CIFAR10_data()
print('Train data shape: ', x_train.shape)
print('Train labels shape: ', y_train.shape)
print('Validation data shape: ', x_val.shape)
print('Validation labels shape: ', y_val.shape)
print('Test data shape: ', x_test.shape)
print('Test labels shape: ', y_test.shape)
layer1_neuron=500
layer2_neuron=500
layer3_neuron=500
number_of_class=10
batch_size=200

    #my neural network   

def neural_network(x_train):
    hidden_layer_1={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072,layer1_neuron])),
        'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer1_neuron]))
         }
    hidden_layer_2={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer1_neuron,layer2_neuron])),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer2_neuron]))
        }
    hidden_layer_3={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer2_neuron,layer3_neuron])),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer3_neuron]))
        }
    output={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer3_neuron,number_of_class])),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([number_of_class]))
        }

    l1=tf.add(tf.matmul(x_train,hidden_layer_1['weights']),hidden_layer_1['biases'])
    l1=tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2=tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_layer_2['weights']),hidden_layer_2['biases'])
    l2=tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3=tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_layer_3['weights']),hidden_layer_3['biases'])
    l3=tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output=tf.add(tf.matmul(l3,output['weights']),output['biases'])

    return output


    # for splitting out batches of data
def next_batch(num, data, labels):
    idx = np.arange(0 , len(data))
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    idx = idx[:num]
    data_shuffle = [data[ i] for i in idx]
    labels_shuffle = [labels[ i] for i in idx]

    return np.asarray(data_shuffle), np.asarray(labels_shuffle)


def traning_neuralNetwork(x_train,y_train):
    total_epochs=10
    total_loss=0
    epoch_loss=0
    batch_size=200
    num_batch = int(np.ceil(49000/batch_size))
    prediction=neural_network(x)
    cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y))
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range (total_epochs):

            total_loss=0
            for _ in range (num_batch):
                x_train,y_train=next_batch(batch_size,x_train,y_train)
                _,epoch_loss=sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict={x:x_train,y:y_train})
                total_loss+=epoch_loss
            print('Epoch ',epoch, " loss = ",total_loss)

        print("Traning Complete!")
        correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
        accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
        print('accuracy',accuracy.eval({x:x_test,y :y_test}))


        traning_neuralNetwork(x_train,y_train)
```

**I am facing error that logits and labels of cost function are not of same shape **

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1329     try:
-> 1330       return fn(*args)
   1331     except errors.OpError as e:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1314       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1315           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1316 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1422             self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1423             status, run_metadata)
   1424 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    515             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 516             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    517     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[200,10] labels_size=[1,200]
     [[Node: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3 = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3/Reshape, softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3/Reshape_1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-aeb4ef85487e> in <module>()
----> 1 traning_neuralNetwork(x_train,y_train)

<ipython-input-16-a54e1136abe5> in traning_neuralNetwork(x_train, y_train)
     67             for _ in range (num_batch):
     68                 x_train,y_train=next_batch(batch_size,x_train,y_train)
---> 69                 _,epoch_loss=sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict={x:x_train,y:y_train})
     70                 total_loss+=epoch_loss
     71             print('Epoch ',epoch, " loss = ",total_loss)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    906     try:
    907       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 908                          run_metadata_ptr)
    909       if run_metadata:
    910         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1141     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1142       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1143                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1144     else:
   1145       results = []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1322     if handle is None:
   1323       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1324                            run_metadata)
   1325     else:
   1326       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1341         except KeyError:
   1342           pass
-> 1343       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1344 
   1345   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[200,10] labels_size=[1,200]
     [[Node: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3 = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3/Reshape, softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3/Reshape_1)]]

Caused by op 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3', defined at:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2698, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2808, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-17-aeb4ef85487e>", line 1, in <module>
    traning_neuralNetwork(x_train,y_train)
  File "<ipython-input-16-a54e1136abe5>", line 59, in traning_neuralNetwork
    cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 250, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1957, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    labels=labels, logits=logits, dim=dim, name=name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1871, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2
    precise_logits, labels, name=name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 7142, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    name=name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3306, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1669, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[200,10] labels_size=[1,200]
     [[Node: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3 = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3/Reshape, softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg_3/Reshape_1)]]
```

Comment: The shape of logits is [batch_size, num_classes] whereas your labels are [1, batch_size]. I guess, you need some so called one-hot encoded labels, so that labels is also of shape [batch_size, num_classes].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels `y_train` need to be one-hot encoded:

```
y_train = tf.one_hot(indices=y_train, depth=10)
```

See my comment

Comment: but now i am getting another error.
error:
setting an array element with a sequence.